# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to migrate a CRA react application to NX, following steps on the [official site](https://nx.dev/latest/react/migration/migration-cra)

When I hit `nx serve`

I am facing the following error:

> ERROR in C:/dev/nx-dev/scandy/node_modules/@react-pdf/png-js/dist/png-js.browser.es.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\dev\nx-dev\scandy\node_modules@react-pdf\png-js\dist'

> ERROR in C:/dev/nx-dev/scandy/node_modules/@react-pdf/pdfkit/dist/pdfkit.browser.es.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\dev\nx-dev\scandy\node_modules@react-pdf\pdfkit\dist'

Knowing that: before I start migration my project worked fine.

***npm version: 6.14.11***

***node version: 14.16.0***

I've tried to hit `npm install zlib` yet I get

> Cannot find module './zlib_bindings'

Comment: For some reason, VSCode inserted ```import e from 'express'``` at the top of my file in react, and it generated this error. Hope this helps someone else...

Comment: That was the issue for me. I got import e from 'express' inserted too.

Answer (score 26):

For some reason, VSCode inserted import e from 'express' at the top of my file in react

```
import { response } from 'express';
```

I delete the above `import` line and then the problem is resolved, all the errors are gone after the above change.

Comment: Thank you. This got imported into my Angular project instead of the one from `@angular/router` and I didn't notice.

Comment: Thank you!! For me it was `import { set } from "express/lib/application";` Anyone know why VS code does this?

Answer (score 7):

For me it was the code:

```
import { response } from 'express'
```

This was entered automatically by VSCode at the beginning of the file.
Deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's about Webpack 5 and its default config you use for React app. I followed an advice from here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4817#issuecomment-824316899 and React NX docs for how to use custom webpack config.

Create a custom webpack config, say, in /apps/myapp/webpack.config.js and reference it in `workspace.json` instead of `"webpackConfig": "@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack"`. It should be `"webpackConfig": "apps/myapp/webpack.config.js"`.

Content for `webpack.config.js`:

```
const nrwlConfig = require("@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js");

module.exports = (config, context) => {
  // first call it so that @nrwl/react plugin adds its configs
  nrwlConfig(config);

  return {
    ...config,
    node: undefined
  };
};
```

So, this config change makes webpack correctly understand what polyfills are needed.

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
const nrwlConfig = require("@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js");

module.exports = (config, context) => {
  // first call it so that @nrwl/react plugin adds its configs
  nrwlConfig(config);

  return {
    ...config,
    resolve: {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),  
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Go Search Icon in VSCode search "express" you may get things like

   ```js
   import { text } from 'express'
   import { Router } from 'express'
   import { X,Y,Z } from 'express'
   ```
2. delete this line your app will work fine

Answer (score 2):

In my case was because I tried to type 'Text' and suddenly, the autocomplete added me this line on top:

```
import { text } from 'express';
```

Just deleted it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you using webpack,you can add

```
  config.resolve.alias= {
        zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib')
  },
```