# NodeJS express module messes up other imports

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-modules

I am making a react app in typescript with the express module. My app compiles fine, but when I add this import line:

```
import { express } from 'express';
```

I get about 30 "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve " errors in seemingly unrelated modules. Example:
[example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY1Zk.png)

Keep in mind, this is just with the import statement, not even using the module.

I've tried rebuilding my node_modules, have tried importing in different ways, but everything produces this same weird set of errors. I believe the issue is the same as in this question: [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001182/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-zlib?newreg=9c506c6665a14bdfb7ff9d6d2ca0c4ad)

My package.json file looks like this if it helps. Let me know if other files would be helpful. Thank you!

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "axois": "^0.0.1-security",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.15",
    "octokit": "^2.0.10",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.12",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: seems your trying to bundle express into a clientside script, which is not possible, express is serverside package

Comment: Yes, coming to the realization that I need a backend. That is definitely what happened.